# Add a column using calculations involving the first element of value's group

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example dataframe:

```
prop1  prop2  prop3  value
a      x      1      2
a      x      2      3
a      y      1      4
a      y      2      5
b      x      1      6
b      x      2      7
b      y      1      8
b      y      2      9
```

I need to add a calculated column where the value is, for example, divided to the first element of its group:

```
prop1  prop2  prop3  value  calculated
a      x      1      2      2/2
a      x      2      3      3/2
a      y      1      4      4/4
a      y      2      5      5/4
b      x      1      6      6/6
b      x      2      7      7/6
b      y      1      8      8/8
b      y      2      9      9/8
```

Honestly, I don't know how to implement this. I tried:

```
df['calculated'] = \
    df['value'] / df.groupby(['prop1', 'prop2']).agg('first')['value']
```

but it gives me `ValueError: cannot join with no level specified and no overlapping names`.

How to calculate this column?

Comment: Do you want the string `'2/2'` or the value `2/2=1`?

Comment: @QuangHoang The second one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `transform` on the series `groupby`:

```
df['calculated'] = df['value'].div(df.groupby(['prop1', 'prop2'])['value']
                                 .transform('first')
                              )

Output:

  prop1 prop2  prop3  value  calculated
0     a     x      1      2    1.000000
1     a     x      2      3    1.500000
2     a     y      1      4    1.000000
3     a     y      2      5    1.250000
4     b     x      1      6    1.000000
5     b     x      2      7    1.166667
6     b     y      1      8    1.000000
7     b     y      2      9    1.125000
```